# How can I make an NLA strip longer to fit more keyframes?

Tags: nla-editor

I made an animation and dropped it as an NLA strip - now I'd like to tweak that strip to add more keyframes and make the strip longer.

I thought that the Extend (<kbd>E</kbd> key) function does that - but no it only stretches the strip. I don't want to scale the strip, because then I'd have to scale down the keyframes to actually fit more of them in my strip - and I can easily break the animation timing while attempting this.

How can I make an NLA strip longer to fit the extra keyframes?

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the NLA editor
2. Select the strip you want to make longer
3. Open the properties panel with the <kbd>N</kbd> key
4. Go to the *Action Strip* tab
5. Enable the *Sync Length* checkbox - this will make the strip longer if you tweak it, making the underlying action longer.

Answer (score 1):

An NLA strip has a set of 6 properties that are mathematically interrelated.  I think there are basically five degrees of freedom.

[image]

Action Extents determines what subset of the base action is sampled for the NLA.  Keyframes outside those boundaries aren't used.

Scale can be used to slow down or speed up the strip.

Repeat lets you loop things if you want.

The Strip Extents at the top determine where in the timeline of the animation the strip exists.

If you were not using the Sync Length option suggested by Unfa, then you could alter the Action Extents > End Frame to include the new keyframes you create.  Blender will update the Strip Extents when you alter the end frame.